# Firebase cloud function; unable to reach firestore database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a firebase cloud function (http request) in which I want to update a document in my firestore database

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.body


// Create payment
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body

    // Create payment
    try {
      console.log(id)
      console.log('test before db call')

      admin.firestore().collection('payments').doc(id).update(
        {
            status: "paid"
        }
      ).then(() => {
          console.log('success')
      })

      console.log('test after db call')

      res.send('ok')
    } catch (e) {
      res.send('not ok')
    }
  })
```

Function is deploying, `console.log(id)` is correct but whenever I call `admin.firestore()` it doesn't print anything anymore.
Commenting that part prints 'promise resolved'
I have the impression I can't access or use wrong syntax to get to the Firestore db but I can't see why?

Firebase logs are printing:

> Function execution started
>
> tr_........ (id)
>
> test before db call
>
> Function execution took 1103 ms, finished with status code: 200

Comment: This doesn't look like complete code.  You have a try with no catch, and I don't see where you're sending a response to the client.  Could you rework your sample to show the minimal code that deals with Firestore that doesn't work the way you expect?  If you think there's a problem with just Firestore, then isolate your code to just that bit.

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the promise returned by `update()` correctly.  You need to wait until that promise is resolved before sending the response.  Right now, you are sending the response without waiting for the database update to complete, which means the Cloud Functions could shut down all the asynchronous work after it returns.  `then` does not block your code.  It merely lets you add a callback to the async work.  You should only sent the response after completion:

```
  admin.firestore().collection('payments').doc(id).update(
    {
        status: "paid"
    }
  ).then(() => {
      console.log('success')
      res.send('ok')    // send response here
  })
```